# drop down menu looks weird in form? (with javascript)

Tags: html, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to do a drop down menu form in a similar manor to my example, and it decides to show the whole thing without dropping down or anything. The selecting still works, it just displays wrong. I checked the console for errors, it's all clean, and my function is working properly. I know there's probably a hundred more proper ways to do this, but I tried a bunch of things different than the example and they don't do anything. What I really want to know is what in particular could be causing this to happen, and what precisely do i have to change to make it drop up and down? This is my form code:

```
<form name="form" action="dhtml.html" id="f1">
    <select id="s1" multiple size="2" onChange="changepics()">
        <option value="L" selected>Lylat System<br/></option>
        <option value="T" >Talon IV<br/></option>
        <option value="J" >Jhoto Region<br/></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing the issue because you are using the 'size' and 'multiple' attributes in the 'select' element. Try the following. It should resolve your issue:

```
<form name="form" action="dhtml.html" id="f1">
    <select id="s1" onChange="changepics()">
        <option value="L" selected>Lylat System</option>
        <option value="T" >Talon IV</option>
        <option value="J" >Jhoto Region</option>
    </select>
</form>
```